# Python script for get minimum product price having maximum reviews

Tags: python, selenium

Technical task.

- user visits amazon.com website
- user fills out a search field with the product name and activates
  search ==>
- a page with search results is displayed.
- user looks for the product having maximum reviews
- count user extracts minimum product price (with applied discount - if
  any) from the page
- user assigns amazon_price = product price
- user visits bestbuy.com website
- user chooses United States country
- user fills out a search field with the product name and activates
  search ==>
- a page with search results is displayed.
- user looks for the product having maximum reviews count
- user extracts minimum product price (with applied discount - if any)
  from the page
- user assigns bestbuy_price = product price

> ```
> import pytest
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>
> from conftest import driver
>
> first_dict = {}
> second_dict = {0: 0}
>
>
> @pytest.mark.parametrize("url, search_locator, products_locator, price_locator, review_locator ", [
>     ("https://www.amazon.com/", "//input[@name = 'field-keywords']", "//div[@class = 'a-section']",
>      "span.a-price-whole", "span.s-underline-text"),
>     ("https://www.bestbuy.com/", "//input[@class = 'search-input']", "//div[@class = 'embedded-badge']",
>      "div.priceView-hero-price span:first-child", "span.c-reviews")])
> def test_shopping(driver, url, search_locator, products_locator, price_locator, review_locator):
>     product = 'samsung galaxy s22'
>
>     driver.get(url)
>
>     if url == "https://www.bestbuy.com/":
>         driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@class = "us-link"]').click()
>
>     search_nav = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, search_locator)
>     search_nav.send_keys(product)
>     search_nav.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)  # for windows need to be changed to Keys.ENTER
>
>     names_product = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, products_locator)
>     assert len(names_product) != 0, "Page with product isn't displayed"
>
>     review_counts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(review_locator)
>     products_price = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(price_locator)
>
>     for i in range(len(products_price)):
>         if i >= len(review_counts):
>             break
>
>         review_count_text = review_counts[i].text.strip('()').replace(',', '.')
>         price_count_text = products_price[i].text.strip('$').replace(',', '.')
>
>         if review_count_text == '' or price_count_text == '' or review_count_text == 'Not Yet Reviewed':
>             continue
>
>         review_count = int(review_count_text.replace('.', ''))
>         price_count = float(price_count_text.replace('.99', ''))
>
>         if "amazon" in url:
>             first_dict[review_count] = price_count
>         if "bestbuy" in url:
>             second_dict[review_count] = price_count
>     max_first_value = max(first_dict)
>     max_second_value = max(second_dict)
>     bestbuy_price = second_dict[max_second_value]
>     amazon_price = first_dict[max_first_value]
>
>     # once script completed the line below should be uncommented.
>
>     assert amazon_price > bestbuy_price
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
    search_nav.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)  # for windows need to be changed to Keys.ENTER
```

I don't understand why there's a comment here.
Add an `if sys.platform == ...` and be done with it.
Explain the details in the code, not in a comment.

---

```
    review_counts = ...
    products_price = ...
```

These (and the *_locators) are helpful identifiers, thank you.
Consider revisiting the whole singular vs plural distinction,
for consistency.

---

```
    for i in range(len(products_price)):
        if i >= len(review_counts):
            break
```

We might have computed `max( ... )` across the two lengths,
fine, whatever.
More importantly: It isn't clear why "too many reviews"
leads to invalid data.
At a minimum we need a `# comment` explaining what sort
of bad data has been observed on particular web pages.
We need this to understand what the code is doing,
and also to identify whether next year's web pages still
manifest that behavior, or if perhaps the logic can be pruned.

```
        review_count_text = ...
        price_count_text = ...
```

Those identifiers should probably not have "count" in the middle
of them. They *came* from counts, but they do not contain counts.

I recommend Extract Helper: pass in
`review_counts` / `products_price`
and get back `review_count` / `price_count`.
For one thing, it will let you write a Unit Test
that reveals helpful example text strings to the
maintenance engineers you hire next year.

---

```
        if "amazon" in url:
            first_dict[review_count] = price_count
        if "bestbuy" in url:
            second_dict[review_count] = price_count
```

These are ill-chosen identifiers.
They are unimaginative and unhelpful.
An obvious name would be `amazon_dict`.
But better: use another level of indirection.
Could be [`defaultdict(dict)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)
where we talk about `review_counts[vendor][review_count]`.
Or it could be `review_counts[f"{vendor}_{review_count}"]`.

---

```
    assert amazon_price > bestbuy_price
```

This possibly is true ATM.
But pricing strategies will vary as the months go by.

The parsing code above this seems to be nicely motivated,
turning possibly chaotic web text into well-defined variables
(or signalling fatal error if page format changed).
In contrast, this particular assertion seems like
it belongs one level up in the call stack.
Push the parsing down into a helper function,
and make an assertion on what comes back from it.

---

Overall?

I would not be willing to assign or delegate maintenance
tasks on this code base as written. Adding unit tests
with example HTML text snippets would go a long way
toward explaining the underlying assumptions.
The current code does not yet appear to be ready
for pushing it into production.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is a test assignment I recently wrote for the Trainee position. I will fix it.